# removing table row with jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I can't quite get this javascript working - It's been asked a million times and I've looked at a lot of different examples on SO, but...to no avail.

here's the code:

```
// modifed from http://stackoverflow.com/a/6520723/2128691

var count = 1;
var goal = 0;

$(function() {
    $('#add_goal').click(function() {
        addGoal();
    });
});

$(function() {
    $('#remove_goal').click(function() {
        removeGoal();
    });
});


function addGoal()
{
    $('#goal_form').append('<tr></tr>');
    $('#goal_form').append('<td class="goal_field fields"><input id="goal_goal" name="goal[goal]" placeholder="Students should..." size="30" type="text" /></td>');
    count++;
}

function removeGoal() 
{
    $('tr').remove();
    count--;
}
```

It's very close to working so I think it must just be a small issue - I can add as many fields as I need, and I can remove a row, but only one time.  After removing a goal once, clicking the link again does nothing (although 'add' still works).

Comment: Add $('tr', this).remove();

Answer (score 0, accepted):

got it working with help from this answer:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/6570175/2128691

```
function removeGoal() 
{
    $('#goal_form tr:last').remove();
    count--;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

This line:

```
$('tr').remove();
```

Will delete all rows.

Also, these lines don't make sense

```
$('#goal_form').append('<tr></tr>');
$('#goal_form').
   append('<td class="goal_field fields"><input id="goal_goal" name="goal[goal]" placeholder="Students should..." size="30" type="text" /></td>');
```

1. You're not appending the *td* inside a *tr*.
2. Is `#goal_form` a *table*? If not you can't just append a *table row* to it.

Comment: `#goal_form` is a table.  i changed that code to make it one line though, thanks.

Comment: @dax do you mean you've put the td inside the tr?

Comment: yup, got it working, i added an answer below.  thanks for the help!